# Returning more than one elements from a function

Tags: java

I have a function in Java, but I'm trying to return 3 elements from a function, but so far no luck.

```
public String retrieveStudentInfo() {
    String name = "Miley";
    String grade = "56"
    String ID = "1043"
    return name,grade,ID; //trying to return all the elements in this function.
}
```

based on the function above, I'm trying to return the name,grade and ID at the same time, through a variable like below:

```
String getStudentInfo = this.retrieveStudentInfo();
```

Could anyone please help me on this. I've specified the return data type as String but it wouldn't let me return them.

Comment: A method can only return one item at a time. That item can be an object, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap this properties in some class and then return instead of String the object of class like StudentInfo

```
public class StudentInfo {
    String name;
    String grade;
    String ID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you can't return tuples in java.
You can do like this:

1. Declare a class, `StudentInfo`, which contains 3 attributes of type `String` - `name`, `grade` & `ID`.
2. Define the return value of `retrieveStudentInfo` to be `StudentInfo`.
3. Create an instance of it in the last line of the `retrieveStudentInfo` and return it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String[] retrieveStudentInfo() {
    String name = "Miley";
    String grade = "56"
    String ID = "1043"
    String[] data = new String[] {name ,grade ,ID};
    return data;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, because in the real world, `grade` would be an `int`, and then you can't use a `String` array. You'll either have to generalize to `Object[]` with boxing and casting, or use a better solution.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I understand and totally agree with what you say. But, my intention here is giving a basic answer to a basic question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return this object as String you can do something like this: `return name + “ “ + grade + “ “ + ID;`

It will be complicated however to interpret this String. So better is to return the complete Object.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object called AnswerObject:

Define this object to have 3 public properties of String:

```
public class AnswerObject {
public String Name;
public String Grade;
public String ID;
}
```

Return this object from your method and you will have an answer with 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

User `Tuple` from [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_maven)

```
private static Tuple3<Integer, String, Object> returnThreeElements() {
    return Tuple.of(1, "HelloWorld", new Object());
}
```

get element from `Tuple` can use method like the follow code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tuple3<Integer, String, Object> result = returnThreeElements();
    System.out.println(result._1());
    System.out.println(result._2());
    System.out.println(result._3());
}
```